# Adding a while loop to my code to either re-run the program or terminate based on user input [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm currently in the process of trying to add a while loop to my code that is shown below.  The theory behind what I'm attempting to do is as follows:

As you can see at the very bottom of my code, I confirm the user's reservation and ask if he/she would like to create another.  If the user enters 'yes", I would like the program to re-run.  If no, then the program should terminate.  I'm aware the best way to accomplish this is using a while loop, but I'm having a little difficulty executing this as my textbook is a little confusing on the subject.

I know it's supposed to look something like this (or something along the lines of it):

```
while True:
expression
break
```

Though I can't seem to get it to compile.  Any suggestions?  Below is my code:

```python
user_continue = str(raw_input("Your reservation was submitted successfully.  Would you like to do another?"))

if user_continue != 'yes':

print('Thank you for flying with Ramirez Airlines!')
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to post the entire code?

Comment: I apologize, I'm new here.  I was just pasting my entire code for context purposes.  Do you have a better recommendation?

Comment: Just post only the code enough to reproduce the actual problem. Check this http://sscce.org/

Comment: It compiles fine and there is no error to reproduce.  I'm just asking for advice on how to add a while loop to my entire code.

Comment: Just put the code you want to repeat inside the while loop and at the end of that add something like `if user_continue != 'yes': break`.

Comment: Do you have any advice thefourtheye or did me trying to be as thorough as possible (as the site rules imply) really warrant a down-vote?

Comment: @CoryRamirez People tend to down-vote questions where the user just posts a bunch of code and asks how to do something, since it suggests the poster hasn't taken the time to think about what the "core" of the problem is.

Comment: Submitted code in questions  on Stack Overflow should be a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example or [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Alright, I will keep this in mind for the future.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example that shows how to use a `while` loop:

```
import time

while True:
    print time.ctime()
    print 'Doing stuff...'
    response = raw_input('Would you like to do another? ')
    if response != 'yes':
        break

print 'Terminating'
```

Note that the code inside the `while` loop **must** be indented, unlike the code in your first code block. Indentation is *very* important in Python. Please always ensure that code in your questions (and answers) here is properly indented.

FWIW, the `raw_input()` input function returns a string, so `str(raw_input())` is unnecessary clutter.

---

The end of your code should look something like:

```
user_continue = raw_input("Your reservation was submitted successfully.  Would you like to do another?")    
if user_continue != 'yes':
    break

print('Thank you for flying with Ramirez Airlines!')
```

...

Your print statements are a bit funny. Since you're using Python 2.7 you don't need to do

```
print ('The total amount for your seats is: $'),user_people * 5180
```

you can just do

```
print 'The total amount for your seats is: $', user_people * 5180
```

or if you wish to use Python 3 style, put *everything* you're printing inside the parentheses, like this:

```
print ('The total amount for your seats is: $', user_people * 5180)
```

However, the output will look a bit messy since there will be a space between the `$` and the amount. Please read the python docs to learn how to fix that.

...

Also, you have `import time` inside your loop. Don't do that. Generally, import statements should be at the top of your script before any other executable code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I revised my above code with a while loop but am still receiving an error, do you mind taking a look at my revised code?  Thanks for the advice on the raw_inputs as well, I'll fix them!

Comment: Your last edit just messed up the main `While True:` loop! But I'll add some extra info to my answer.

Comment: I managed to get my program to loop, but even if the user input isn't 'yes' it'll still print the last statement and just re-start the program.  So it works when the input is yes, but not when it's supposed to terminate.

Comment: And just like that I managed to fix it.  Thank you SO much for your help!  The way you explained it helped me understand it a bit better, I really appreciate it!